# How to prevent image upload XSS attacks?

Tags: security, xss, content-security-policy

I recently did a CTF challenge where we needed to do an XSS attack on a site with a Content Security Policy `...  script-src 'self' ...` . This was made possible because the website offered the possibility to upload images, which we used to upload a file containing Javascript code with a GIF header like `GIF89a=alert(document.cookie)//;`.

All we had to do after successfully uploading that image was call that image with something like `http://website.com/<script src=url_to_our_image>` and the code was executed despite the CSP.

Now my question: How could you prevent that? I assume you want to keep CSP at `...  script-src 'self' ...` (you want to trust your own scripts, right?). But what other option would then be left to prevent such an attack? Blacklisting some content of the image, so that it cannot contain code? (I heard that blacklists a generally a bad idea)

Comment: Not having the page vulnerable to xss via the url?

Comment: @GaborLengyel and that would be done by sanitizing the URL? Like removing keywords that can be use to trigger scripts?

Comment: No, by applying proper encoding (eg. html encoding) before writing it to the page, so that `<` becomes `&lt;` and so on.